# How to use 5 by 5 or 7 by 7 kernel size for a deep learning network with 3 by 3 kernels?

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, classification, keras

I am using a `U-Net` architecture. The visual area of the segmentation mask is very small and after learning it is giving a lot of false positives. I am thinking of changing the kernel size of 3 by 3 to 5 by 5. What precautions/care shall I take while creating the model? I am getting issue of dimensionality mismatch if just change 3 by 3 to 5 by 5 kernel size.

Answer (score 0):

The main think you need to be mindful about is the size of the output of your convolutional layer, remember that it's going to be

$$
\frac{W-K+2P}{S} + 1
$$

with your K the kernel size, so if you increase your kernel size the size of your output will decrease faster. You might have to reduce the number of layers. If you're using a framework for which you need to specify input size for each layer then in that case you would need to change that as well.

Comment: I am using an xception net as encoder, where if I use 5 by 5 kernel then it works. But, for decoder part the skip connection don't match. What shall I do?

Comment: ah this is trickier, it will depend on the library (and even what API) you use to build the model. Do you have your code hosted somewhere?

Comment: I have used code from this link: https://www.kaggle.com/meaninglesslives/unet-xception-keras-for-pneumothorax-segmentation